# Is it possible to alter a select2 object after it has been initialised?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, jquery-select2, sonata-admin

I'm using sonata admin bundle to build an admin dashboard. I want to bind some data to a [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) enhanced select box.

The problem is that I can't alter the select2 properties after page load:

```
$(function(){
    $("#select-brand").select2({
       placeholder: "Select report type",
       allowClear: true,
       data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
    });
}):
```

this generates the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Option 'data' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.
```

But even just trying to override the placeholder does not have any effect:

```
$("#select-brand").select2({
    placeholder: "Select report type",
    allowClear: true,
});
```

Comment: @Suman Bogati please undo your edit. the additional code was important

Comment: @GeertWille probably because i dont know about it and/or its not documented in an obvious place. Feel free to enlighten me. Bear in mind I am trying to load content via ajax. The above code is just from the select2 docs

Answer (score 0):

Is this relevant?

In the onload event add the following:

```
$('#selectId').append( $.map(data, function(v, i){ return $('<option>', { val: i, text: v }); }) );
```

Answer (score 0):

consider this related question [select2 destroy and recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898693/set-json-data-from-ajax-and-make-it-serarchable-in-select2-jquery/22928349#22928349).  I had to destroy and recreate the select2 to solve a problem i ran into tonight.  i think this solution will work for you as well.